Textual evidence against Torah being composed as a "Foundation myth"
Some Biblical scholars suggest, that the Five Books of Torah were compiled between the fall of the Israelite Kingdom and the end of the Babylonian exile as a "founding myth" for the newly formed Judaite/Israelite nation.
I'm looking for evidence that might object to this view, in a form "if the Torah was written as a foundational myth, it would be improbable to include such and such passages/words/topics/events"
For example, if the Torah was composed by the Judeans, it would be improbable to make Reuben Jacob's firstborn.

This seems to be attacking a red herring. No one claims that some people got up in the 7th century and decided to make up a whole long story book from scratch. The claim is they put together many different known folk-stories into one work. Each component could be of various ages and have undergone all sorts of adaptations over the years.

@DoubleAA I agree regarding "folk stories", but what are some "stories" you don't put into the foundational myth?

I would recommend the work of Kenneth Kitchen. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Reliability_of_the_Old_Testament

This has been addressed long ago. Among other reasons (is this from Rabbi Herrz? I forget now) -- it would be a profoundly inconvenient foundation myth.

Why not say that we've always been in Israel, rather than acknowledge that Father Abraham was in fact from Mesopotamia and we were not the initial inhabitants of the land?

At the times of King Josiah, the Edomites were no longer allies with Judah, put mildly. Yet Deuteronomy stresses that the Israelites of the desert opted to avoid war with the Edomites, and in fact were commanded to welcome an Edomite convert. Why make up that story if it would be a lot more convenient to whip your people into a religious frenzy against today's boogieman?



Thank you, keep adding!

The Boogeymen were always the great powers to the north and south (Egypt and Bavel or assyria) israel even allied with Aram against greater threats.  Friendly overtures to the other Hebrew nations would not be inconsistent with a Josiah forgery.

The Abraham household is the progenitor of Edom, moav, ammon, and even Aram if you count Eliezer. By showing Abraham left Mesopotamia (and also Egypt) you emphasize that you have made active decisions to be separate from either empire.

Perhaps, as a reference one should use the following reference regarding Hertz Chumash https://www.thetorah.com/article/the-hertz-chumash-a-polemical-defense-of-judaism

To add on to what Shalom said, I remember hearing something along these lines in the name of the kuzari (though I'm not sure I've ever seen it inside):
If the Torah was false/ written hundred of years after it claims to have been written, why and how could we make a claim that 3 million people heard God at Har Sinai? Claiming something like that, if it's not true, make it very easy to deny: "Where are these 3 million people? What happened to them? Why don't we have any knowledge of such a large event, a mere few hundred years later?"
Claiming that one person heard God is a lot easier, because there's no way to refute it. If the Torah was made up, that should've been the go-to story. (Christianity and Islam both utilize this type of 'prophecy' for this exact reason).

The argument against this, though, is that the Har Sinai event might be irrefutable, but the Torah itself says that the people handed the receipt of the Torah over to Moshe, such that any revelation subsequent to the Aseres Hadibros came from Moshe himself on his own. Any discussion to the contrary comes purely from Medrash, which is not a good source for proving the veracity of the Torah minei ubei.

Doesn't the Torah itself testify that God killed the whole generation of Exodus??

@AlBerko Yes, but it’s not like their children were orphans. The generation died early, not immediately. They had enough time to pass the experience on to their children.

@Yehuda but once we accept that the aseres hadibros are true, then we accept that the Torah is telling the truth at least about har Sinai, which means it wasn't made up hundreds of years later, which was the question. (You could also argue that once we accept that har Sinai happened, we accept that Moshe is the writer of the Torah, because he's the 'middleman' during Har Sinai who's recording all of it. And once we accept that, there's no reason to think Moshe lied about the rest of it... But that's a slightly farther jump and also unnecessary to answer the question)

I think, killing the whole generation of Tora receivers is more improbable for a foundation myth than the whole generation attending epiphany.

@AlBerko there's another answer for you, then :-)

The Jews treasured a history of being slaves in Egypt as their national origins.
This would be seen as very demeaning by the world around them. Therefore the
Jews must have been doing so out of religious truth and acceptance of facts.
I believe William F. Albright (famous Biblical Archeologist) is quoted
as expressing this idea.

An interesting idea. Can you elaborate on it a bit, please? Why would the presentation of the Israelites as beating the Egyptian empire would seem demeaning?

I didn't say beating the Egyptians was demeaning in any way. I said admitting their entire nation were bona fide slaves for generations would be demeaning. It also doesn't make sense to escape and move into the immediately neighboring property and advertise you are a bunch of escaped slaves, and keep the story going even when the Egyptians recover and re-emerge as a neighboring superpower. The Egyptians would have every excuse to recapture the Jews as escaped property. Abraham Lincoln would not be born for some time. Jews could say instead that they
tried to enslave us and we defeated them.

If the Torah was written as a foundational myth, it would be improbable for it to include so many Egyptian loan words and be precise at depiction of Egyptian culture going back almost to or over 1000 years (the Hyksos period) as the books by Abraham Shalom Yahuda explain (1) and (2).
As pointed by Harel13, Egypt and Yehudah had close ties for a long perod of time. However, in the 4th year of Yechoyakim, king of Yehudah, the army of pharaoh Necho was smitten by Nebuchadnezzar at Carchemish (Sefer Yirmiyahu 46:2 (witness evidence), as I understand the defeat is also confirmed by outside sources). By the time of the 2nd Temple, Egypt was reduced to a province of Persia. People, who tried to re-built the nation of Yehudah came from Bavel, they spoke Aramaic, not Hebrew and largely forgot anything Egyptian.
(1) A. S. Yahuda "The Accuracy Of The Bible", William Heinemann, London, 1934

The Pharaoh in audience,  invested in gala-robes holding the sceptre, sitting on the throne under a richly decorated canopy, receiving presents and tribute from Asiatic princes introduced by ushers. The prince heading the deputation is wearing a "coat of many colors" Bereshis 37:3 and other places. (I.e. the Yaakov's sons were jealous that Yosef wore a coat of a high rank prince, but they did not.)
The image is interesting, since already at the time of Yoshiyahu Jewish culture was prevalent in Eretz Israel and princes did not wear such coats.
(2) A. S. Yahuda "The Language of the Pentateuch in its Relation to Egyptian", Oxford University Press, London, 1933
The first book is a lighter version of the second, not as technical, easily understood by laymen. If possible, one should try to find the original editions, which carry precise pictures and do not have any missing pages (unlike the reprints) available on Amazon. These are extremely rare, unfortunately.

I agree in principle, but it should be noted that by Yoshiyahu's time the Kingdom of Judah had extensive ties with Egypt, including Egyptian symbols appearing on Judahite seals (e.g., the ankh and scarab on Chizkiyahu's own seals), Egyptian-related names used by the Judahites, Egyptian numerals used in the Judahite measuring systems, and more. So many aspects of Egyptian culture could have logically made their way into a 7th century BCE Torah.

@Harel13 yes. You are suggesting that the Torah could have been written in 7th century BCE, the time of Josiah, I am proving that it could not be written at the time of Ezra (see  the added paragrpah).

Devarim 31:9

ויכתב משה את התורה הזאת ויתנה אל הכהנים בני לוי הנושאים את ארון ברית ה' ואל כל זקני ישראל


Moses wrote down this Teaching and gave it to the priests, sons of Levi, who carried the Ark of Hashem's covenant, and to all the elders of Israel.

(Sefaria's translation)
This passuk clearly states that Moshe wrote the Torah, and Moshe obviously lived well before the fall of the kingdom of Israel.

Sorry for misleading you, I only realized now.
By "textual evidence " I mean, "given the assumption the Torah was written as a foundational myth, it would be improbable to include such and such passages/words/topics/events".

@AlBerko what would constitute an answer then? If you assume the Torah was written later than the events it describes, and is mostly myth, then anything in it which would seem to prove its authenticity could be explained away as being used on purpose by the authors to make it look authentic...

Anything could be explained away under any proposed theory of authorship. No assertion in this realm can be proven mathematically. The question is about evidence that makes it seem less likely that the Torah was composed as a foundation myth. Its own assertion that it isn't seems to me to be such evidence, but is a great deal less convincing to this point than features that would seem to conflict with the typical purposes of a foundation myth.

If someone in Josiah's time had perfect knowledge of the past, they could compose the Torah in that setting without any anachronisms. Perfect representation of Abraham's time wouldn't be evidence that it was written in Abraham's time.
